# How float to binary conversion works

Tags: c, stm32

I was looking for solution how convert float value to binary in STM32 and I found this:

```
float foo = 1.23;
uint32_t bar;
bar = *((uint32_t *)&foo);
```

My question is how does it works? I know it's some kind of pointer conversion, but I don't understand how precisely does it works.

Comment: It needs to be noted that the above will not convert the float value 123.456 into the integer value 123 (or any other "number" that is anywhere close to 123.456).  It merely makes the "raw" bits of the float representation (Google "IEEE floating point") accessible via the uint32_t variable.

Comment: `&foo` returns the address of the float value in storage.  `(uint32_t *)` "casts" that address from pointer-to-float into pointer-to-uint32_t.  Then the very first `*` "dereferences" the pointer back to a (uint32_t) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally *nothing happens*. The `float` is already in a binary representation; the cast merely tells the compiler that it should treat the 32 bits in the variable as a 32 bit unsigned integer instead of a single precision floating point value.